# Reference book for stochastic processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, applied-mathematics

I am looking for a good reference book for properties of stochastic processes for applied research. What I would like the reference to have is a collection of results on a large list of stochastic processes, e.g., formulas for stopping times, relations to other processes, etc.. In some sense, I am looking for a book that does for stochastic processes what Polyanin has done for differential equations or Aczel for functional equations (and perhaps Wikipedia for probability distributions). Does such a book/reference exist?